# How do power calculations for binomial distribution work?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, binomial-distribution, statistical-power

I'll use R for the example calculations.

I want do design a controlled study. A usual one-tailed A/B test on the web.

So, let's say we have a base conversion rate of 10% and we want to determine our needed sample size for $\alpha = 5\%$ and $1 - \beta = 80\%$. The minimum relative uplift in conversion we care about is 10%, so our second hypothetical conversion is 11%.

```r
power.prop.test(p1 = 0.1, p2 = 0.11, power = 0.8, sig.level = 0.05, alternative = "one.sided")$n
```

This will give us the required $n = 11619.07$. Evan Miller's calculator gives [14313](https://www.evanmiller.org/ab-testing/sample-size.html#!10;80;5;10;1) (probably because it's two-sided)

So what I thought it's doing is this:

- Determines an outcome for the first conversion p1 that has a probability $1 - \alpha$ of happening:

```r
n <- seq(1000, 20000, 1000)  # for a series of Ns
k <- qbinom(1 - 0.05, n, 0.1)
```

- Determines the probability of this "fringe" outcome happening given that the real conversion is p2.

```r
power <- 1 - pbinom(k, n, 0.11)
```

- Takes a minimum N at which power is $>= 80\%$.

```r
data.frame(n, k, power)

       n    k     power
1   1000  116 0.2532189
2   2000  222 0.4255792
3   3000  327 0.5550530
4   4000  431 0.6642745
5   5000  535 0.7428058
6   6000  638 0.8121849
```

This gives us about 6000, which is obviously not correct.

What am I missing? All of the guides and explanations I found on the Internet (including university materials) explain it the way I'm doing it, but it's obviously doesn't match the tools everyone uses.

Comment: Why is 6000 "obviously not correct"?  It takes a *lot* of data to distinguish an 11% response from a 10% response!

Comment: @whuber it's not too much but too little. According to both the online calculators for sample size and `power.prop.test` function in R the required sample for these exact conditions is more than 10k. I'm trying to figure out why the difference and what's wrong conceptually with my understanding.

Comment: Your online and `R` calculations are for a *two-sample* test whereas you appear to describe a *one-sample* test.  The difference between those settings roughly should lead to a factor of two difference in needed sample sizes.  The ratio 11619:6000 is a little less than that because the variance of a 10% rate is a little less than the variance of an 11% rate.

Comment: @whuber And how would I go about designing the two-sample test "manually" like I did with the one-sample?

Comment: If you would like to modify your question, then please feel free to do so, because nobody has posted a reply yet.  But first you might want to [search relevant posts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=binomial+two+sample+size+power) for existing answers.

Comment: Can't make sense of this: "So, let's say we have a base conversion rate of 10% and we want to determine our needed sample size for $\alpha = 5\%$ and $1 - \beta = 80\%$. The minimum relative uplift in conversion we care about is 10%, so our second hypothetical conversion is 11%." Can you please explain 10%, 10% 11%?